# How do I use darknet architecture for image classification with fastai

Tags: python, darknet, fast-ai

I could make training run with for example squeezenet, but I'm new to this so I'm not able to figure out what other architectures (like darknet, xception or xresnet) require to be instantiated successfully.

In my notebook I tried:

```
arch = models.Darknet(num_classes = 2, num_blocks = 4) // whats numblocks
learn2 = cnn_learner(data = data, base_arch = arch , metrics=[accuracy, error_rate], pretrained = True)
```

I get error:

````
----> 1 arch = models.Darknet(num_classes = 2,num_blocks = 4)
      2 learn2 = cnn_learner(data = data, base_arch = arch , metrics=[accuracy, error_rate], pretrained = True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/vision/models/darknet.py in __init__(self, num_blocks, num_classes, nf)
     31         super().__init__()
     32         layers = [conv_bn_lrelu(3, nf, ks=3, stride=1)]
---> 33         for i,nb in enumerate(num_blocks):
     34             layers += self.make_group_layer(nf, nb, stride=2-(i==1))
     35             nf *= 2

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable```
````

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.models.html#Darknet)

> Create a Darknet with blocks of sizes given in num_blocks, ending with
>   num_classes and using nf initial features. Darknet53 uses num_blocks =
>   [1,2,8,8,4].

learn more about darknet [here](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/)